# How to change click-event in knockout templates loop to mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-events

I have this html:

```
 <div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: 'tb-template', foreach: Items,  afterAdd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');} }" class="group accordion ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix" ></div>
```

with the template:

```
 <script type="text/html" id="tb-template" >
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Text' + TextId}, click: $root.SelectedText" class="group ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" >
        <div class="accordion-header  ui-widget-header">
        <table>
               <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span data-bind="text:Title"></span></td>
                    </tr>          
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>
     </div>
</script>
```

When clicking each element in my Items list I show a div with Item-information like this:

```
<div class="" data-bind="with: SelectedText">           
    <label>Id:</label><span data-bind="text: Id"></span> 
    <h1 data-bind="text: Title"></h1>
    <label>Description:</label><span data-bind="value: Description" class="description"></span>         
</div>
```

The last div is responding to the click-event in the accordion. Now i´d like to make it respond to mouseover/hover instead of click. I have tried to just switch the event-name, but this obviously doesn´t work. How can I make this respond the way I want?

Comment: Have you tried with the `event` binding? So with `data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Text' + TextId}, event: { mouseover: $root.SelectedText}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html For more detail on how to properly use the event binding.

```
 <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Text' + TextId}, event:{ mouseover: $root.SelectedText}" class="group ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" >
```

The above code will enable the next element in the accordion.  Keep in mind that this only ENABLES the next element, you'll need a pretty large edit to actually get it to disable on mouseout.